# Authentication Oauth on Windows Mobile Emulator Fails with HTTPS

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, oauth

Lets set the stage
Doing a windows phone app, and trying to authenticate using Hammock OAuth library http://hammock.codeplex.com/
Language is C#.

I got to the point where I make the request, get the url with the token, then I am redirected in the WebBrowser control, but as soon as I enter my login and password I am redirected to a HTTPS URL, then that screen with the warning saying "We're having trouble with this site's security certificate", with the option of going back or continuing (Same one we see in windows when there is something unusual with the Certificate).

When I choose to continue, I get a page saying "We can't display this page right now", "Error: Cannot find server or DNS error"

I have tryed this directly on the IE Browser on the emulator and it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the currently supported certificates for Windows Phone. Without knowledge of the issuer of the certificate on the server you're accessing, I'm thinking it may not be one of these.

[SSL Root Certificates for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521150%28VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: So this makes sense to a point. Why does it work on the phones IE and not on the WebBrowser control?

Comment: I would have thought the same would have applied in IE if this was the issue, I apparently overlooked your suggestion that this worked. Perhaps an idea to post the specifics on this on the AppHub and see if Microsoft can clarify why one works and the other doesn't.